# Constructing a simple interpreter

Tags: c#, architecture, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I’m starting a project where I need to implement a light-weight interpreter.
The interpreter is used to execute simple scientific algorithms.
The programming language that this interpreter will use should be simple, since it is targeting non- software developers (for example, mathematicians.)

The interpreter should support basic programming languages features:

- Real numbers, variables, multi-dimensional arrays
- Binary (+, -, *, /, %) and Boolean (==, !=, <, >, <=, >=) operations
- Loops (for, while), Conditional expressions (if)
- Functions

[MathWorks MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/) is a good example of where I’m heading, just much simpler.
The interpreter will be used as an environment to demonstrate algorithms; simple algorithms such as finding the average of a dataset/array, or slightly more complicated algorithms such as [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) or [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA).

Best/Most practical resource I found on the subject is Ron Ayoub’s entry on Code Project ([Parsing Algebraic Expressions Using the Interpreter Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/InterpreterPatternParsing.aspx)) - a perfect example of a minified version of my problem.

The Purple Dragon Book seems to be too much, anything more practical?

The interpreter will be implemented as a .NET library, using C#. However, resources for any platform are welcome, since the design-architecture part of this problem is the most challenging.

Any practical resources?

(please avoid “this is not trivial” or “why re-invent the wheel” responses)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would write it in [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). Write the grammar, let ANTLR generate a C# parser. You can ANTLR ask for a parse tree, and possibly the interpreter can already operate on the parse tree. Perhaps you'll have to convert the parse tree to some more abstract internal representation (although ANTLR already allows to leave out irrelevant punctuation when generating the tree).

Answer (score 3):

It might sound odd, but Game Scripting Mastery is a great resource for learning about parsing, compiling and interpreting code.

You should really check it out:

[http://www.amazon.com/Scripting-Mastery-Premier-Press-Development/dp/1931841578](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931841578)

Comment: Outstanding book! The scripting language described in the book is implemented in C# at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Conscript.aspx

Comment: The funny thing is that Alex Varanese and I go way way back, we used to talk on irc in our young teens. Interesting to see that he is an author now. He was a master of x86 assembly.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to examine the source code for an existing interpreter. I've written a javascript interpreter in the D programming language, you can download the source code from http://ftp.digitalmars.com/dmdscript.zip

Walter Bright, Digital Mars

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend leveraging the DLR to do this, as this is exactly what it is designed for.

[Create Your Own Language ontop of the DLR](http://www.dotnetguru.org/us/dlrus/DLR2.htm)

Answer (score 2):

[Lua](http://www.lua.org/) was designed as an extensible interpreter for use by non-programmers.  (The first users were Brazilian petroleum geologists although the [user base has broadened considerably](http://www.wowprogramming.com/) since then.)  You can take Lua and easily add your scientific algorithms, visualizations, what have you.  It's superbly well engineered and you can get on with the task at hand.

Of course, if what you really want is the fun of building your own, then the other advice is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython)?  It's easy to use from .NET and it seems to meet all your requirements.  I understand that python is fairly popular for scientific programming, so it's possible your users will already be familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

> The programming language that this interpreter will use should be simple, since it is targeting non- software developers.

I'm going to chime in on this part of your question.  A simple language is not what you really want to hand to non-software developers.  Stripped down languages require more effort by the programmer.  What you really want id a well designed and well implemented Domain Specific Language (DSL).

In this sense I will second what Norman Ramsey recommends with Lua. It has an excellent reputation as a base for high quality DSLs. A well documented and useful DSL takes time and effort, but will save everyone time in the long run when domain experts can be brought up to speed quickly and require minimal support.

Answer (score 1):

The [Silk](https://github.com/SoftCircuits/Silk) library has just been published to GitHub. It seems to do most of what you are asking. It is very easy to use. Just register the functions you want to make available to the script, compile the script to bytecode and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised no one has mentioned [xtext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xtext) yet. It is available as [Eclipse plugin](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/index.html) and [IntelliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8074-xtext). It provides not just the parser like ANTLR but the whole pipeline (including parser, linker, typechecker, compiler) needed for a DSL. You can check it's source code on Github for understanding how, an interpreter/compiler works.