# Suggestions for writing a programming language?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, interpreter, scripting-language

What tips can you give a person who is looking to write a programming or script language? I
am not worried about how to program nor design a compiler but how to develop one quickly using tools and code generators.

Last time i tried i coded it in c++ and the states and syntax took almost as long as writing the actual logic. I know the follow tools would help.

I was thinking i could generate c++ code and have gcc compile that. Using the tools above how long would you estimate it would take to write a program or script language?

---

Variations on this question have been asked repeatedly, as far back as [Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler). [Here is an incomplete list of SO resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365602/creating-your-own-language#365636) on the topic.

Comment: I've tried cleaning up this question.. I might hack it up further.

Comment: Alright, I've re-focused the title.. and removed extraneous comments in the question.  I think it is a better question now.

Comment: Your "refocusing" removed information like the mention of antlr, and the idea that it would compile to C++.  I think you might have edited too much.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder, removing ANTLR was intentional.  He listed off 5 programming languages that he had "heard" of, and then stated that he had never used them before.  They weren't used in reference to his question about writing a language and didn't add to his question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating your own language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365602/creating-your-own-language)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Estimating how long something like that might take is dependent on many different factors. For example, an experienced programmer can easily knock out a simple arithmetic expression evaluator in a couple of hours, with unit tests. But a novice programmer may have to learn about parsing techniques, recursive descent, abstract representation of expression trees, tree-walking strategies, and so on. This could easily take weeks or more, just for arithmetic expressions.

However, don't let that discourage you. As Jeff and Joel were discussing with Eric Sink on a [recent Stack Overflow podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/podcast-36/), writing a compiler is an excellent way to learn about many different aspects of programming. I've built a few compilers and they are among my most memorable programming projects.

Some classic books on building compilers are:

- [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/) (also known as The Dragon Book)
- [The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) (also known as SICP)
- [Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/wirth/books/AlgorithmE0/)

Answer (score 5):

Dave Hanson, who with Chris Fraser spent 10 years building [one of the world's most carefully crafted compilers](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/lcc/), told me once that one of the main things he learned from the experience was not to try to write a compiler in C or C++.

If you want to develop something quickly, don't generate native code; target an existing virtual machine such as the CLR, JVM, or the [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) virtual machine.  Generate code using maximal munch.

Another good option if you're writing an interpreter is just to use the memory management and other facilities of your underlying programming language.  Parse to an AST and then interpret by tree walk of the AST.   This will get you off the ground fast.  Performance is not the greatest, but it's acceptable.  (Using this technique I once wrote a PostScript interpreter in Modula-3.  The first implementation took a week and although it later underwent some performance tuning, primarily in the lexer, it never had to be replaced.)

Avoid LALR parser generators; use something that saves your time, like ANTLR or the [Elkhound](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~smcpeak/elkhound/) GLR parser generator.

Comment: Is there more about the Postscript interpreter? (I have a collection.)

Comment: @droog it's part of the source of [ldb](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/ldb/)

Answer (score 3):

The classic books on compiler design are

"Principles of Compiler Design" by Alfred V. Aho and Jeffrey D. Ullman.  It's been around quite some time now and its pink knight and green dragon are well known to at least a couple of generations of CS students.

Also...

"Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" by Alfred V. Aho, Monica S. Lam, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey D. Ullman

If you're interested in writing a compiler then these are undoubtedly the best places to start.

Answer (score 3):

> As a person who knows C++ very well,
>   what tips can you give a person who 
>   is looking to write a programming or script language?

Don't do it. (or at least think long and hard before you do!)

If you're trying to write a scripting language to expose the methods/properties of some custom-written objects, it would be better to implement those in Java (or .NET/VB or all those icky Microsoftisms) and then use one of the [Bean Scripting Framework](http://jakarta.apache.org/bsf/) languages as your scripting language. (with whatever the equivalent is on the Microsoft end.)

Comment: ok, fine. :p 
I'm just saying it 'cause I spent several weeks writing a parser for a crude scripting language, but figured out later that I could've just used Javascript or Python by writing my object model and exposing it to an existing scripting language. Who wants to learn a new language?

Comment: +1, we already have way too many programming languages. If it's really necessary, there are frameworks to create domain specific languages.

Comment: @WimCoenen With that kind of thinking, maybe the world should have stop improving buildings, cars, phones, planes, weapons, etc. If a 1,000 people do the same thing, at least 1 person will eventually venture off to see how to improve it. That's called progress.

Comment: @SpicyWeenie: my "kind of thinking" is that it is inefficient for everybody to build their own car. Inefficiency impedes progress.

Comment: @WimCoenen It's illogical and senseless to think everyone wants to build their own car. Some like the design concepts, manufacturing, rebuilding, troubleshooting, maintenance and just plain driving it. How many times have the light bulb and phone been improved on? That would count as inefficient by your process. It the world were to follow your model, we would still be on horses throwing rocks and beating each other with sticks. Your model doesn't promote ingenuity nor creativity, because everything we take for granted stems from an older idea repeated done beforehand.

Comment: @SpicyWeenie: "It's illogical and senseless to think everyone wants to build their own car." Exactly. Leave the car building to the guys who have the means to assemble a team of experts and innovate, like Elon Musk did with Tesla Motors.

Comment: @WimCoenen Except ... writing a compiler is not analogous to building a car. You don't need tons of raw material, rented space, endless financial capital, and a team of specific engineers just to buid one prototype, and then mass produce it if the design is defensible. This is a compiler. This is not Tesla motors.

Comment: I take issue with your perspective, especially in light of it being a 5-year-old answer. OP said (and my emphasis): "I am not worried about how to program nor design a compiler but how to develop one **quickly** using tools and code generators." This implies an emphasis of using it to get something else done, not focusing on the joy or learning of programming language design itself. Having done something similar at the time, I shared my experience. I found it MUCH easier to implement in Java than C++.

Answer (score 3):

Any questions about compilers will have an answer "go read dragon book, read that book, this book..." on SO regardless of their content in a few minutes. So I skip that part (like I was telling in the first place). Reading these books to learn how to use the tools you want, is about as useful as reading about angular momentum to learn how to ride a bike.

So, to answer what you asked, without questioning your intention, I can easily recommend antlr and antlrworks for starters. You can generate your AST easily (where the real magic happens, I think) and debug your grammar visually. It generates a good portion of a working compiler for you.

If you know your stuff and want to have more control or don't like antlr, you can use [lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) parser generator and [ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) state machine compiler (have special support for lexing) together.

If you don't need too much performance and since you plan to generate C/C++ code, you can skip doing any optimizations yourself and leave that stuff to your C/C++ compiler.

If you can live with a slow runtime, you can further shorten your development effort just doing interpretation, since it is often easier to implement dynamic features this way.

Answer (score 3):

I think everybody is missing one very important point.

***WHY*** do you want to write a compiler / interpreter / parser etc.

This will seriously determine a lot of what you do.

I have worked on quite a few language implementations, some rather weird, some domain specific, some simply scripted progress through command environments (often where the command environment was later hidden). Each required different levels of skill.

Many books available. One I loved was a BYTE book : Threaded Interpreted Languages - bet it's out of print.

Simple script engines can be crafted with a few evening's thinking and a bit of trial and error.

But I bet there are online courses now that will save you a ton of time.

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly recommend looking at existing bytecode interpreters. If you can make your language fit into CIL (.NET) or Java (or even others such as Python or Parrot), you'll save yourself all the effort of making a workable supporting environment and can get on with experimenting with language concepts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on writing an interpreter or compiler, don't do it because you want to write the next big thing.  Write it because you already have a purpose for it in mind or to learn.  If you do this you may find that you've accidentally written the next big thing.

Answer (score 1):

A good tool that I've used for LALR is the [GOLD Parsing System](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/).  It's free, the grammer is Backus-Naur Form, and there are multiple examples, including engines written in C#, VB.NET, Java and others.  This lets you write a grammer, compile the grammer to a file, and then use an engine to parse the grammer.

As recommended above, I would recommend targeting a byte code of some kind, like IL.  This will allow you to leverage the enormous amounts of existing frameworks.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get into writing a compiler to reduce your language to assembly/machine, then your next option is to write a compiler to a byte-code language virtual machine, such as the JVM, PVM or .NET.

Of course, if you don't even want to do that - you just want to create your own "domain specific language", I would build it in Common Lisp.   Lisp macros provide a rather straight-forward method of creating whatever syntax you want and parsing it into Lisp.  And you don't have worry about byte-code or assembly.  Of course, you need to learn Lisp.