# writing a programmung language

Tags: programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestions for writing a programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453870/suggestions-for-writing-a-programming-language)

I have used many programming languages and after several years of experience I have finally decided to make a language with my friends. I know that this is a task not for the faint of heart. We are devoted to the task and are going to make sure that this gets completed.

Now I wanted to start off by asking: what are the steps to writing a programming language? What should we start off with (ex. The parser)?

Any answer is helpful!

Comment: What kind of language? An interpreted scripting language or something with a compiler?

Comment: Also we wanted to use c or c++ to program it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your first language, then work on all parts of it at the same time, start with a mini language spec and extend it feature by feature. Unless a its a domain specific language you should use a language that comes close to what you try to implement so that later you might be able to write a conversion tool to get a bootstrapping version of your compiler.