# Designing and Implementing a programming language, What is the next step?

Tags: programming-languages

So i have design a programming languages and got far enough that i wrote example code and started writing BNF. I want to know is there a checklist of things i may want to do before writing the rest of my BNF? what should i do afterward? i am afraid implementation will take a long time (its as complex as and maybe more then C++). What are things i should do or things i should consider?

Comment: Many related questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Designing+and+Implementing+a+programming+language especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365602/creating-your-own-language

Answer (score 2):

Get peer review on what you've done so far. Language design is *hard* - it's likely that an extra pair of eyes (or several) would help to find some areas where you could improve it *before* you go too far down the implementation side. (In particular, if it's more complex than C++ are you sure that's necessary?)

Answer (score 1):

If it is more complex than C++, it probably needs redesign. A lott of C++'s complexity comes from the need to provide C compatibility and so to graft features ion top of the less than wonderful C declaration syntax. If you don't need to support an exsiting language, it's hard to see how such complexity can be justified.

Having designed and implemented a few languages myself, I recommend an invremental approach:

- design  small subset
- implement it
- use it

With the lessons learned, design a  somewhat larger subset and repeat.