# How to implement a language using a functional language?

Tags: haskell, resources, language-design, compiler-theory

I prefer *Haskell*.

I already know How to create my own language with Procedural Language (for example: C, Java, Python, etc).

But, I know *How to create my own language with Functional Language* (for example `Haskell`, `Clojure` and `Scala`).

I've already read:

### Internet Resources

1. [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours)
2. [Real World Haskell - Chapter 16.Using Persec](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html)
3. [Writing A Lisp Interpreter In Haskell](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/lisp-in-haskell.html)
4. [Parsec, a fast combinator parser](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/download/parsec/parsec.html)
5. [Implementing functional languages: a tutorial](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/pj-lester-book/)

### Books

1. [Introduction Functional Programming Using Haskell 2nd Edition -- Haskell](http://www.amazon.co.jp/Introduction-Functional-Programming-Prentice-Computer/dp/0134843460)

### StackOverflow (but with procedural language)

1. [Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler)
2. [create my own programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662410/create-my-own-programming-language)

### Source

1. [Libraries and tools/HJS -- Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Libraries_and_tools/HJS)

Are there any other good links/sources? I would like to get some more.

Comment: Just a question, but why would you want to create your own programming language? What is this for?

Comment: Could you explain what your question is? I see a bunch of links, but no real question.

Comment: @Blender It seems that he wants to get more links.

Comment: http://meta-alternative.net/calc.pdf

Comment: What are you looking for that these articles don’t give you? I think *Write Yourself a Scheme in 18 Hours* and *Implementing Functional Languages* together are more than adequate to show you how to efficiently implement whatever functional language you care to think up.

Answer (score 4):

[Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/) is frequently used in programming language classes, and is available online for free. It uses Scheme.

[Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) is another incredible book dealing with type systems (including implementation), though only available in dead tree format. It uses ML (which represents a significant family of functional languages that I noticed was missing from your list).

[Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) (formerly called PLT Scheme) is a functional language that emphasizes making your own sub-language.

Answer (score 3):

read also:

- Christian Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) book,
- Andrew Appel's [Compile with Continuations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/cwc.html) (and also his book *Modern compiler implementation in ML* isbn:0521582741)

I also think that Jacques Pitrat's latest book [Artificial Beings - the conscience of a conscious machine](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470611791) will give you very interesting insights.

Answer (score 0):

Take also a look at [Compiler.HOOPL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hoopl%20Compiler.Hoopl) and [Control.Unification](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unification-fd%20Control.Unification) libraries, and [uuagc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuagc%20UUAGC) attribute grammar preprocessor. You also can read https://wiki.ittc.ku.edu/lambda/images/e/e3/Modular-interpreters.pdf on writing modular interpreters in Haskell. Also note that Parsec is not very fast and for non-toy projects Happy/Alex may be suited better.